# How change source with a bash function

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following (bash) function to quickly change virtual environments:

```
changeEnv() { "source ~/VirtualEnvironments/$1/bin/activate"; }
```

And when I run it with

```
changeEnv my_env
```

I get

```
-bash: source ~/VirtualEnvironments/my_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

But if I run

```
source ~/VirtualEnvironments/my_env/bin/activate
```

It works. So I know it is reaching at the right place.

I figure this might have something to do with the timing of the evaluation of $1, but really I have no clue why something so seemingly simple is not working.

Comment: But if you run `"source ~/VirtualEnvironments/my_env/bin/activate"` at the shell, **with the quotes**, you get the same error. So why would you expect the quotes to need to be added to the function, when they break your code's operation if present at the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put quotes around a string with spaces, you make that string into a single word in shell.

The first word in a command is treated as the command to run. So, when you were putting the entire command in spaces, you're telling the shell to look for a command like `source ~/VirtualEnvironments/my_env/bin/activate`, **with the space and the `~` as part of the command's filename**.

Because those *aren't* part of the filename, but rather are syntax (in the first case, intended to separate words; in the second case, intended to be replaced with the user's home directory), they need to be unquoted:

Note that the only thing we're quoting here is the `$1` -- that way we ensure that even if your environment name contains spaces or wildcards, only a single argument (only a single "word" in shell syntax) is passed after the command name `source`.

```
changeEnv() { source ~/VirtualEnvironments/"$1"/bin/activate; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Did not realize the quotes mattered but that makes sense